# Unable to load Map Chart in Angular 7 using HighMaps 7

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular7

I am trying to load a map chart as described in the below sample,the title and other controls are displayed but the actual map is not. Please let me know what I am missing here

[image]

Source :  [HighMaps for Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts)

Component.ts file below

```
displayMapChart(){this.mapChart = new MapChart({ 
chart: {
  map: 'custom/world-robinson'
},
title: {
  text: "Regions"
},
mapNavigation: {
  enabled: true,
  buttonOptions: {
    alignTo: 'spacingBox'
  }
},
colorAxis: {
  min: 0
},
series: [
  {
    type: 'map',
    name: 'Text here',
    states: {
      hover: {
        color: '#BADA55'
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}'
    },
    allAreas: false,
    data: [
      ['fo', 0],
      ['um', 1],
      ['us', 2],
      ['jp', 3],
      ['sc', 4],
      ['in', 5],
      ['fr', 6],
      ['fm', 7],
      ['cn', 8],
      ['pt', 9],
      ['sw', 10],
      ['sh', 11],
      ['br', 12],
      ['ki', 13],
      ['ph', 14],
      ['mx', 15],
      ['es', 16],
      ['bu', 17],
      ['mv', 18],
      ['sp', 19],
      ['gb', 20],
      ['gr', 21],
      ['as', 22],
      ['dk', 23],
      ['gl', 24],
      ['gu', 25],
      ['mp', 26],
      ['pr', 27],
      ['vi', 28],
      ['ca', 29],
      ['st', 30],
      ['cv', 31],
      ['dm', 32],
      ['nl', 33],
      ['jm', 34],
      ['ws', 35],
      ['om', 36],
      ['vc', 37],
      ['tr', 38],
      ['bd', 39],
      ['lc', 40],
      ['nr', 41],
      ['no', 42],
      ['kn', 43],
      ['bh', 44],
      ['to', 45],
      ['fi', 46],
      ['id', 47],
      ['mu', 48],
      ['se', 49],
      ['tt', 50],
      ['my', 51],
      ['pa', 52],
      ['pw', 53],
      ['tv', 54],
      ['mh', 55],
      ['cl', 56],
      ['th', 57],
      ['gd', 58],
      ['ee', 59],
      ['ag', 60],
      ['tw', 61],
      ['bb', 62],
      ['it', 63],
      ['mt', 64],
      ['vu', 65],
      ['sg', 66],
      ['cy', 67],
      ['lk', 68],
      ['km', 69],
      ['fj', 70],
      ['ru', 71],
      ['va', 72],
      ['sm', 73],
      ['kz', 74],
      ['az', 75],
      ['tj', 76],
      ['ls', 77],
      ['uz', 78],
      ['ma', 79],
      ['co', 80],
      ['tl', 81],
      ['tz', 82],
      ['ar', 83],
      ['sa', 84],
      ['pk', 85],
      ['ye', 86],
      ['ae', 87],
      ['ke', 88],
      ['pe', 89],
      ['do', 90],
      ['ht', 91],
      ['pg', 92],
      ['ao', 93],
      ['kh', 94],
      ['vn', 95],
      ['mz', 96],
      ['cr', 97],
      ['bj', 98],
      ['ng', 99],
      ['ir', 100],
      ['sv', 101],
      ['sl', 102],
      ['gw', 103],
      ['hr', 104],
      ['bz', 105],
      ['za', 106],
      ['cf', 107],
      ['sd', 108],
      ['cd', 109],
      ['kw', 110],
      ['de', 111],
      ['be', 112],
      ['ie', 113],
      ['kp', 114],
      ['kr', 115],
      ['gy', 116],
      ['hn', 117],
      ['mm', 118],
      ['ga', 119],
      ['gq', 120],
      ['ni', 121],
      ['lv', 122],
      ['ug', 123],
      ['mw', 124],
      ['am', 125],
      ['sx', 126],
      ['tm', 127],
      ['zm', 128],
      ['nc', 129],
      ['mr', 130],
      ['dz', 131],
      ['lt', 132],
      ['et', 133],
      ['er', 134],
      ['gh', 135],
      ['si', 136],
      ['gt', 137],
      ['ba', 138],
      ['jo', 139],
      ['sy', 140],
      ['mc', 141],
      ['al', 142],
      ['uy', 143],
      ['cnm', 144],
      ['mn', 145],
      ['rw', 146],
      ['so', 147],
      ['bo', 148],
      ['cm', 149],
      ['cg', 150],
      ['eh', 151],
      ['rs', 152],
      ['me', 153],
      ['tg', 154],
      ['la', 155],
      ['af', 156],
      ['ua', 157],
      ['sk', 158],
      ['jk', 159],
      ['bg', 160],
      ['qa', 161],
      ['li', 162],
      ['at', 163],
      ['sz', 164],
      ['hu', 165],
      ['ro', 166],
      ['ne', 167],
      ['lu', 168],
      ['ad', 169],
      ['ci', 170],
      ['lr', 171],
      ['bn', 172],
      ['iq', 173],
      ['ge', 174],
      ['gm', 175],
      ['ch', 176],
      ['td', 177],
      ['kv', 178],
      ['lb', 179],
      ['dj', 180],
      ['bi', 181],
      ['sr', 182],
      ['il', 183],
      ['ml', 184],
      ['sn', 185],
      ['gn', 186],
      ['zw', 187],
      ['pl', 188],
      ['mk', 189],
      ['py', 190],
      ['by', 191],
      ['cz', 192],
      ['bf', 193],
      ['na', 194],
      ['ly', 195],
      ['tn', 196],
      ['bt', 197],
      ['md', 198],
      ['ss', 199],
      ['bw', 200],
      ['bs', 201],
      ['nz', 202],
      ['cu', 203],
      ['ec', 204],
      ['au', 205],
      ['ve', 206],
      ['sb', 207],
      ['mg', 208],
      ['is', 209],
      ['eg', 210],
      ['kg', 211],
      ['np', 212]
    ]
  }
]});}
```

Template.html

```
<mat-card class="md-elevation-z7">
   <div style="height: 346px;" [chart]="mapChart"></div>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't load map data. Check this description from `highcharts-angular` official wrapper, which I recommend you to use: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-map-for-highmaps. Below you will find the online example of Angular with highcharts map (using highcharts-angular wrapper).

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ChartComponent } from "./chart.component";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HighchartsChartModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**chart.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_map from 'highcharts/modules/map';
HC_map(Highcharts);
require("./worldmap")(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  chart;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "mapChart";
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      map: 'myMapName'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js">World, Miller projection, medium resolution</a>'
    },
    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      buttonOptions: {
        alignTo: 'spacingBox'
      }
    },
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Random data',
      states: {
        hover: {
          color: '#BADA55'
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}'
      },
      allAreas: false,
      data: [
        ['fo', 0],
        ['um', 1],
        ['us', 2],
        ['jp', 3],
        ['sc', 4],
        ['in', 5],
        ['fr', 6],
        ['fm', 7],
        ['cn', 8],
        ['pt', 9],
        ['sw', 10],
        ['sh', 11],
        ['br', 12],
        ['ki', 13],
        ['ph', 14],
        ['mx', 15],
        ['es', 16],
        ['bu', 17],
        ['mv', 18],
        ['sp', 19],
        ['gb', 20],
        ['gr', 21],
        ['as', 22],
        ['dk', 23],
        ['gl', 24],
        ['gu', 25],
        ['mp', 26],
        ['pr', 27],
        ['vi', 28],
        ['ca', 29],
        ['st', 30],
        ['cv', 31],
        ['dm', 32],
        ['nl', 33],
        ['jm', 34],
        ['ws', 35],
        ['om', 36],
        ['vc', 37],
        ['tr', 38],
        ['bd', 39],
        ['lc', 40],
        ['nr', 41],
        ['no', 42],
        ['kn', 43],
        ['bh', 44],
        ['to', 45],
        ['fi', 46],
        ['id', 47],
        ['mu', 48],
        ['se', 49],
        ['tt', 50],
        ['my', 51],
        ['pa', 52],
        ['pw', 53],
        ['tv', 54],
        ['mh', 55],
        ['cl', 56],
        ['th', 57],
        ['gd', 58],
        ['ee', 59],
        ['ag', 60],
        ['tw', 61],
        ['bb', 62],
        ['it', 63],
        ['mt', 64],
        ['vu', 65],
        ['sg', 66],
        ['cy', 67],
        ['lk', 68],
        ['km', 69],
        ['fj', 70],
        ['ru', 71],
        ['va', 72],
        ['sm', 73],
        ['kz', 74],
        ['az', 75],
        ['tj', 76],
        ['ls', 77],
        ['uz', 78],
        ['ma', 79],
        ['co', 80],
        ['tl', 81],
        ['tz', 82],
        ['ar', 83],
        ['sa', 84],
        ['pk', 85],
        ['ye', 86],
        ['ae', 87],
        ['ke', 88],
        ['pe', 89],
        ['do', 90],
        ['ht', 91],
        ['pg', 92],
        ['ao', 93],
        ['kh', 94],
        ['vn', 95],
        ['mz', 96],
        ['cr', 97],
        ['bj', 98],
        ['ng', 99],
        ['ir', 100],
        ['sv', 101],
        ['sl', 102],
        ['gw', 103],
        ['hr', 104],
        ['bz', 105],
        ['za', 106],
        ['cf', 107],
        ['sd', 108],
        ['cd', 109],
        ['kw', 110],
        ['de', 111],
        ['be', 112],
        ['ie', 113],
        ['kp', 114],
        ['kr', 115],
        ['gy', 116],
        ['hn', 117],
        ['mm', 118],
        ['ga', 119],
        ['gq', 120],
        ['ni', 121],
        ['lv', 122],
        ['ug', 123],
        ['mw', 124],
        ['am', 125],
        ['sx', 126],
        ['tm', 127],
        ['zm', 128],
        ['nc', 129],
        ['mr', 130],
        ['dz', 131],
        ['lt', 132],
        ['et', 133],
        ['er', 134],
        ['gh', 135],
        ['si', 136],
        ['gt', 137],
        ['ba', 138],
        ['jo', 139],
        ['sy', 140],
        ['mc', 141],
        ['al', 142],
        ['uy', 143],
        ['cnm', 144],
        ['mn', 145],
        ['rw', 146],
        ['so', 147],
        ['bo', 148],
        ['cm', 149],
        ['cg', 150],
        ['eh', 151],
        ['rs', 152],
        ['me', 153],
        ['tg', 154],
        ['la', 155],
        ['af', 156],
        ['ua', 157],
        ['sk', 158],
        ['jk', 159],
        ['bg', 160],
        ['qa', 161],
        ['li', 162],
        ['at', 163],
        ['sz', 164],
        ['hu', 165],
        ['ro', 166],
        ['ne', 167],
        ['lu', 168],
        ['ad', 169],
        ['ci', 170],
        ['lr', 171],
        ['bn', 172],
        ['iq', 173],
        ['ge', 174],
        ['gm', 175],
        ['ch', 176],
        ['td', 177],
        ['kv', 178],
        ['lb', 179],
        ['dj', 180],
        ['bi', 181],
        ['sr', 182],
        ['il', 183],
        ['ml', 184],
        ['sn', 185],
        ['gn', 186],
        ['zw', 187],
        ['pl', 188],
        ['mk', 189],
        ['py', 190],
        ['by', 191],
        ['cz', 192],
        ['bf', 193],
        ['na', 194],
        ['ly', 195],
        ['tn', 196],
        ['bt', 197],
        ['md', 198],
        ['ss', 199],
        ['bw', 200],
        ['bs', 201],
        ['nz', 202],
        ['cu', 203],
        ['ec', 204],
        ['au', 205],
        ['ve', 206],
        ['sb', 207],
        ['mg', 208],
        ['is', 209],
        ['eg', 210],
        ['kg', 211],
        ['np', 212]
      ]
    }]
  };

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    this.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  update_chart() {
    const self = this,
      chart = this.chart;

    chart.showLoading();
    setTimeout(() => {
      chart.hideLoading();

      self.chartOptions.series = [
        {
          data: [10, 25, 15]
        }
      ];

      self.updateFromInput = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**chart.component.html:**

```
<div class="boxChart__container">
    <div>
        <highcharts-chart
            id="container" 
            [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
            [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
            [(update)]=updateFromInput
            [oneToOne]="true"
            style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
        </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax7gdr

Comment: I have come across the above implementation, but I am trying to use HighMaps 7